# Highcharts point selecting trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to select all points in category in single mouse click.
For example, i have two series, and when i click the one of point in one of series, with index=3, point in second series should be selected too. This is my solution:

```
var selecting = false;
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart : {
        type:'column'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect : true,
          point: {
            events: {
              select: function (e) {
                    if (selecting) return;
                    selecting = true;
                    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i ++) {
                        chart.series[i].points[e.target.index].select(true,true);
                  }
                    selecting = false;
              },
            }
          }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    },{
        data: [129.9, 21.5, 126.4, 29.2, 44.0, 76.0, 235.6, 48.5, 116.4, 94.1, 25.6, 154.4]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfq7y8m9/1/
It works only when i keep Control button.

How to get the same solution whithout holding Control button. Only with mouse click?

Many thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Because calling `Point.select()` function inside `point.events.select` causes `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error (endless loop), you can use `Point.setState()` function and set `selected` property manually. Take a look at the example posted below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.select

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vk25qLy5/

Comment: Thanks! =)
I just forget e.preventDefault )
Unfortunatelly, i have no enough of karma, for vote for your answer (